# How to Add Alerts and/or Notification to a Folder with Restricted Access within a Library?

Tags: custom-alert-templates

Let me start by saying I am very new to SharePoint...so my knowledge is limited.

My organization has a SharePoint (2013 version) site and has created me a folder and given me Full Control permission.  I have about 6 folders within that folder of which I have given Contributor permission to different people...they only have access to their folder.

Is there a way for me to alter them or send them a notification when a document has been added to their particular folder only? I hope this makes sense.

I will appreciate of any assistance I can get.